# Can I have asp:Repeater inside asp:Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to create `asp:Table` where I can add rows using `asp:Repeater` like:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblRepeater">
 <asp:Repeater runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TableRow runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" Text=""></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" Text=""></asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Table>
```

But when I try to do this It gives me error:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'. 
'asp:Repeater' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'.
```

Am I doing somethig wrong or it is impossible to use Repeater in Table?

Comment: I think you could do such thing with HTML table not with asp:Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your example is slimmed down or represents your actual use case, but in this case you'd be better of using either a `GridView` which will generate a table structure based off of a given Data Source, or creating the `<table>` structure yourself and then placing a repeater inside it:

```
<table>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" /></td>
              <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" /></td>
          </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: It is slimmed down as you say and it is a part of FormView. I prefer to use asp components where I can easily set properties and other settings, but I realised that in case of table I don't need any. This example works fine, thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to see this done not in a `<table>` but in an `<asp:Table>`. Therein lies the difficulty I face. I'd like to access this wrapping table and turn visibility off if it has no rows.